# Using a column in a WHERE IN clause for two times

Tags: mysql

I have a set of products, each of which have a set of filters associated with them. Hence, I have:

```
table: products {id, name}
table: filters {id, name, type}
table filters_to_products {id, filter_id, product_id}
```

There are no foreign keys used. Everything is implemented logically.

My filters are of two types: **size** and **color**

***Problem***: I want to select products which have at least one color from a set of colors and at least one size from a set of sizes, hence `WHERE IN` clause basically comes to my mind, but that does not work, because:

```
select * from products 
left join filters_to_products 
  on products.id = filters_to_products.product_id 
where filters_to_products.filter_id in (1,2,3,4);
```

The above query, though technically works but has mistake, filters of types color and size are mixed in the same parenthesis, hence I think of making two different WHERE IN clause, which nevertheless, does not work for one column at the same time.

What should I do? I think the solution has something to do with nested queries, if so, how should I approach that?

Comment: `filter_to_products` is a table, therefore `filter_to_products IN (1,2,3,4)` is nonsense. This query will not run as-is. If you can share some sample data and desired results we can help you more easily since it's not clear what you need from your explanation alone.

Comment: need to see filters or filters_to_products structure.  I dont' know if you're using key'd pairs or what column 'size' and color are in nor which table... sample data expected results always a plus in a question!

Comment: I have clearly stated my problem. My question has nothing to do with syntactical issues (which are created while typing the question)

Comment: If you have people asking questions, then the question doesn't make sense to them.  it may make sense to you; but if they don't understand; they can't help.  Keep in mind we offer help freely.  Those unwilling to help themselves, likely will not get the help for which they ask.

Comment: @xQbert I have updated the question.

Comment: @xQbert You're right. I edited the question. If you see my score, you see I'm not a newbie in asking/answering questions. I know that.

Comment: Note that id in the junction table serves no purpose

Comment: @MostafaTalebi  Thanks updating the question clarified!

Comment: @strawberry Yes you are right. In a big database, such think could result in redundancy and performance-drop. In my case, that does no harm.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that F.Type has values of at least {Size,Color}

Then all we need to do is join the three tables and make sure we filter based on those types.  We then ensure we have a distinct count of records for types of 2.... this will guarantee a product has at least a size and color attribute.
There are ways to check that it ONLY has those two as well but I don't believe that is the question.. yet...

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Name
FROM PRODUCTS P
INNER JOIN FILTERS_TO_PRODUCTS FP
 on P.ID = FP.Product_ID
INNER JOIN FILTERS F
 on F.ID = FP.Filter_ID
WHERE F.Type in ('Size','Color')
GROUP BY P.ID, P.Name
HAVING Count(Distinct F.Type) = 2
```

Comment: me always; but I missing it. not anymore...wow..  no I always make my left joins act like inner just to confuse maintenance teams. (and myself)

Comment: Sorry, there is an issue. What about the certain set of filter IDs? Your query just matches any product having both size and color, but does not matches further based on filter IDs.